# what to happen vs. what to say

Tags: infinitives, wh-questions

Is "I don't know what to happen" natural on a par with the other sentences?

> I don't know what to do.

> I don't know what I should do.

> ? I don't know what to happen.

> I don't know what should happen.

Comment: This is a request to proofread multiple sentences. If you're unsure about some particular aspect of **one** of these sentence, please ask that in a question and tell us what research you've done so far, and what you're still confused about. [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> I don't know what to happen.

is impossible.

It puts "I" as subject and "what" as an object, but "happen" is intransitive, and I can't happen something.

If it said "I don't know what **is** to happen.", that would be grammatical, meaning *I don't know what will happen*.